# camunda spring boot starter with gradle gives processEngineConfigurationImpl bean missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, camunda, spring-starter

My issue is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842156/when-setting-embeddedservletcontainerfactory-with-camunda-spring-boot-processeng) and it's kinda straightforward: copy paste service from maven to gradle project makes starters non operational.

[Here](https://github.com/berndruecker/camunda-spring-boot-amqp-microservice-cloud-example) is the project I've used as an example and it starts like a charm:

```
Spring-Boot:  (v2.2.5.RELEASE)
Camunda BPM: (v7.12.0)
Camunda BPM Spring Boot Starter: (v3.4.1)

INFO 227460 --- [main] com.camunda.demo.springboot.Application  : Starting Application on archbox with PID 227460 (/home/user/ide/IdeaProjects/camunda-spring-boot-amqp-microservice-cloud-example/target/classes started by user in /home/user/ide/IdeaProjects/camunda-spring-boot-amqp-microservice-cloud-example)
INFO 227460 --- [main] com.camunda.demo.springboot.Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
INFO 227460 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
INFO 227460 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
INFO 227460 --- [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
INFO 227460 --- [main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO 227460 --- [main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1095 ms
INFO 227460 --- [main] .c.b.s.b.s.r.CamundaJerseyResourceConfig : Configuring camunda rest api.
INFO 227460 --- [main] .c.b.s.b.s.r.CamundaJerseyResourceConfig : Finished configuring camunda rest api.
INFO 227460 --- [main] org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot              : STARTER-SB040 Setting up jobExecutor with corePoolSize=3, maxPoolSize:10
INFO 227460 --- [main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'camundaTaskExecutor'
INFO 227460 --- [main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.cfg               : ENGINE-12003 Plugin 'CompositeProcessEnginePlugin[genericPropertiesConfiguration, camundaEngineHistoryConfiguration, camundaIdGeneratorConfiguration, camundaProcessEngineConfiguration, camundaDatasourceConfiguration, camundaJobConfiguration, camundaHistoryConfiguration, camundaMetricsConfiguration, camundaAuthorizationConfiguration, failedJobConfiguration, SendEventListenerPlugin, disableDeploymentResourcePattern, eventPublisherPlugin]' activated on process engine 'default'
INFO 227460 --- [main] org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot              : STARTER-SB020 ProcessApplication enabled: autoDeployment via springConfiguration#deploymentResourcePattern is disabled
INFO 227460 --- [main] o.c.b.s.b.s.event.EventPublisherPlugin   : EVENTING-001: Initialized Camunda Spring Boot Eventing Engine Plugin.
INFO 227460 --- [main] o.c.b.s.b.s.event.EventPublisherPlugin   : EVENTING-003: Task events will be published as Spring Events.
INFO 227460 --- [main] o.c.b.s.b.s.event.EventPublisherPlugin   : EVENTING-005: Execution events will be published as Spring Events.
INFO 227460 --- [main] o.c.b.s.b.s.event.EventPublisherPlugin   : EVENTING-007: History events will be published as Spring events.
INFO 227460 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
INFO 227460 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
INFO 227460 --- [main] org.camunda.bpm.engine                   : ENGINE-00001 Process Engine default created.
INFO 227460 --- [main] o.c.b.s.b.s.w.f.LazyInitRegistration     : lazy initialized org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazyProcessEnginesFilter@69364b2d
INFO 227460 --- [main] o.c.b.s.b.s.w.f.LazyInitRegistration     : lazy initialized org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazySecurityFilter@52f6900a
```

However [project](https://github.com/im-infamou5/camundatest) I've copied from part of sources gives following:

```
Spring-Boot:  (v2.1.3.RELEASE)
Camunda BPM: (v7.12.0)
Camunda BPM Spring Boot Starter: (v3.4.1)

 INFO 227891 --- [main] com.test.camundatest.Application         : Starting Application on archbox with PID 227891 (/home/user/ide/IdeaProjects/gradle-camunda-service/build/classes/java/main started by user in /home/user/ide/IdeaProjects/gradle-camunda-service)
 INFO 227891 --- [main] com.test.camundatest.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
 INFO 227891 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
 INFO 227891 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
 INFO 227891 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 14ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
 INFO 227891 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
 INFO 227891 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
 INFO 227891 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
 INFO 227891 --- [main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d980ca4f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
 INFO 227891 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
 INFO 227891 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
 INFO 227891 --- [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
 INFO 227891 --- [main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
 INFO 227891 --- [main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
 INFO 227891 --- [main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1883 ms
ERROR 227891 --- [main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineServicesConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'processEngine'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.CamundaBpmAutoConfiguration$ProcessEngineConfigurationImplDependingConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'processEngineConfigurationImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 INFO 227891 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
 WARN 227891 --- [main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
 INFO 227891 --- [main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-06 10:21:45.754 ERROR 227891 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field processEngineConfigurationImpl in org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.CamundaBpmAutoConfiguration$ProcessEngineConfigurationImplDependingConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
- Bean method 'processEngineConfigurationImpl' in 'CamundaBpmConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl' processEngineConfiguration


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl' in your configuration.
```

What should I add / change in configs to make my "gradle" service work like "maven" one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly there's key difference in the way that two given projects retrieving connection and data source details.

For instance it's enough for me to put this into maven project properties to point camunda engine to my db (rest left "as-is"):

```
spring.datasource.url=${POSTGRES_ADDRESS:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myservice}
spring.datasource.username=${POSTGRES_USER:postgres}
spring.datasource.password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:12345}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

while same config just doesn't work for gradle completely, obscurely complaining about `processEngineConfigurationImpl` bean absence when all what engine needs is database connection details.

So that's what I figured:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:config.xml"})
public class Config {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl processEngineConfiguration() throws IOException {
        SpringProcessEngineConfiguration config = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
        config.setDataSource(dataSource());
        config.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
        config.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate("true");
        config.setJobExecutorActivate(true);
        config.setAuthorizationEnabled(true);
        config.setDefaultSerializationFormat("application/json");
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        config.setDeploymentResources(resolver.getResources("classpath:/bpmn/*.bpmn"));
        List<ProcessEnginePlugin> processEnginePlugins = new ArrayList<>();
        config.setProcessEnginePlugins(processEnginePlugins);
        return config;
    }
}
```

And it works:

```
  Spring-Boot:  (v2.1.3.RELEASE)
  Camunda BPM: (v7.13.0)
  Camunda BPM Spring Boot Starter: (v7.13.0)

INFO 378753 --- [main] com.myname.myservice.Application   : Starting Application on pc with PID 378753 (/home/user/IdeaProjects/myservice/build/classes/java/main started by user in /home/user/IdeaProjects/myservice)
INFO 378753 --- [main] com.myname.myservice.Application   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
INFO 378753 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
INFO 378753 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
INFO 378753 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 7ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
INFO 378753 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
INFO 378753 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
INFO 378753 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 7ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
INFO 378753 --- [main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f04798b1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO 378753 --- [main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c95872e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO 378753 --- [main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse
INFO 378753 --- [main] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myservice (PostgreSQL 12.1)
WARN 378753 --- [main] o.f.c.internal.database.base.Database    : Flyway upgrade recommended: PostgreSQL 12.1 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested.
INFO 378753 --- [main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.010s)
INFO 378753 --- [main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "public": 1
INFO 378753 --- [main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
INFO 378753 --- [main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
INFO 378753 --- [main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
INFO 378753 --- [main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO 378753 --- [main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
INFO 378753 --- [main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
INFO 378753 --- [main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
INFO 378753 --- [main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@642c6461
INFO 378753 --- [main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
INFO 378753 --- [main] org.camunda.feel.FeelEngine              : Engine created. [value-mapper: CompositeValueMapper(List(org.camunda.feel.impl.JavaValueMapper@a047bdb)), function-provider: org.camunda.bpm.dmn.feel.impl.scala.function.CustomFunctionTransformer@173b1af1, configuration: Configuration(false)]
INFO 378753 --- [main] org.camunda.bpm.engine                   : ENGINE-00001 Process Engine default created.
INFO 378753 --- [main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor       : ENGINE-14014 Starting up the JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor].
INFO 378753 --- [ultJobExecutor]] org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor       : ENGINE-14018 JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor] starting to acquire jobs
INFO 378753 --- [main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'asyncExecutor'
INFO 378753 --- [main] i.micrometer.influx.InfluxMeterRegistry  : publishing metrics to influx every 1m
INFO 378753 --- [main] org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot              : STARTER-SB040 Setting up jobExecutor with corePoolSize=3, maxPoolSize:10
INFO 378753 --- [main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'camundaTaskExecutor'
INFO 378753 --- [main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
INFO 378753 --- [main] n.d.b.g.s.s.GrpcServerLifecycle          : gRPC Server started, listening on address: *, port: 8081
INFO 378753 --- [main] org.camunda.bpm.container                : ENGINE-08024 Found processes.xml file at file:/home/user/IdeaProjects/myservice/build/resources/main/META-INF/processes.xml
INFO 378753 --- [main] org.camunda.bpm.container                : ENGINE-08023 Deployment summary for process archive 'application':
```

As a sidenote - for unknown reason sql dialect is very important for bpm so this one is mandatory to set like this:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

and not to forget to please flyway if used:

```
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate = true
```